# How do I populate the QuickFix list with argdo make?

Tags: vim, macvim

I'm using a simple compiler for W3C's Nu HTML Checker, so that when I call `:make` inside Vim, the active document is validated as HTML. This works fine when I'm validating one file—the QuickFix list is populated correctly. However, when I run `:argdo make`, only the output from make from the last file is present in the current QuickFix list. For example, suppose my argument list consists of `File1.html` and `File2.html`. And `File1.html` contains errors but `File2.html` is clean. Now when I call `:argdo make` and `File1.html` is validated BEFORE `File2.html`, then there will be no errors in the current QuickFix list. I know that Vim holds onto the last ten QuickFix lists and I can browse them with `:colder` and `:cnewer`, but this is not what I want. When I call `:argdo make`, I want the output from make from all the files in the argument list to be shown in the current QuickFix window. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:argdo make` runs `:make` for each argument so you get one quickfix list per argument.

If you want to have every error for every argument in a single quickfix list, then  you need to run `:make` only once, but for all the arguments:

```
:make ##
```

See `:help :_##`.

---

Side note: when you are done, consider submitting your compiler for inclusion into the Vim runtime.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you. I did not write the compiler, I got it from this site: [link](https://vimandgit.com/posts/vim/advanced/neovim-and-vim-w3c-nu-html-validator-batch-validate-html.html).
Here is the compiler

`let current_compiler = "w3c-html-validator"`
`CompilerSet makeprg=vnu\ $*\ --asciiquotes\ '%'`
`CompilerSet errorformat=\"file:%f\":%[0-9]%#\.%c-%l\.%[0-9]%#:\ %m`

Sorry for the edits, I'm new here.